# Hiding the Taskbar in Windows10, Using Python

Tags: python, hide, taskbar

We are having a prank competition at the office, and we are only allowed to use Python.
the prank involves: taking a screenshot of the Desktop, Moving all the Apps from the Desktop, and using the screenshot as the new wallpaper (I Hope U got it).
The issue is I'm not able to make the taskbar disappear, so they can open the Apps with the taskbar.....

**I need a way to hide the taskbar (in any way or form)**

TNX

Answer (score 0):

```
nircmd.exe win hide class Shell_TrayWnd
nircmd.exe win show class Shell_TrayWnd
```

try running with subprocess in python